# how setup windirstat to show folder size in Gb?

Tags: windows, windirstat

I have [installed](https://windirstat.net/) windirstat and it show folder size in `Kb`. Is there a way to setuop it for showing size in Gb?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I use WinDirStat all the time, verified the behavior, and the units used are based on the size of the folder so WinDirStat uses (Bytes,KB,MB,GB,TB).  No settings were changed.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: That doesn't match any UI portion I can find within WinDirStat

Comment: Look at tray icon. it shows popups with diractory sizes

Comment: Option is in the settings dialog, the default settings have the setting enabled, you must have uncheck it.  If I get around to submitting answer I will